# Creating a square matrix whose elements is 1 with certain condition and 0 otherwise

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the data frame:

```
set.seed(1234)
n = 10
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(n,0,200), d=rbinom(n,1,.5))
```

Now I want to crate a matrix `a` with n by n dimension whose element `a[i,j]=1` , if `(dat[j,1]==x[i]& dat[j,2]==1)`, and 0 otherwise.

The following codes work correctly:

```
a <- matrix(,ncol=n, nrow=n)

for(i in 1:n){
  a[i,] <- (dat$x==dat$x[i] & dat$d==1)
}
```

But is there a way to create the `a` variable with `outer()` or similar other function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `diag()`, to convert `dat$x` to the diagonal of a matrix. We add the logical condition `"==1"` to turn the binary matrix into a boolean one.

```
diag(dat$d)==1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another vectorized option

```
a <- matrix(FALSE,ncol=n, nrow=n)
a[row(a)==col(a)] <- dat$d==1
```